# SImulating cloud storage services with docker containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud

For app development purposes, I think that it would be a nice feature to have docker containers that could act as, for example AWS S3 service or Azure Blob storage, so that we could learn what doesn't work...

Are there any docker containers that act like a cloud storage device?

Comment: Not sure about S3, but Azure has a storage emulator called **Azurite**. Please check it out.

Comment: I was about to propose the [localstack docker](https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/installation/#docker) solution but the topic got closed just before ^^ On my side I don't use it, I developed myself some `fakeS3` and `fakeDynamoDB` (JSON based) classes in `NodeJS`. Non only it ables to have them running instantly as soon as I run my server locally (without relying on another tool being up) but as well, I can directly have an eye on the DB since I made it JSON based... Quite handy ! :)